# Hook up HTML inputs to a python function using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to setup an updated algorithm with my existing flask site.

Right now, it works with taking in one input and passing it to a function.

I want to expand it to work with 6 additional, existing inputs already on the index page.

Here is the flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from manabase import generate_lands

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', lands="")


@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    color_identity = request.form['colorid']
    landcount = request.form['max_land_count']
    whitecount = request.form['white_pip_count']
    bluecount = request.form['blue_pip_count']
    blackcount = request.form['black_pip_count']
    redcount = request.form['red_pip_count']
    greencount = request.form['green_pip_count']
    result = generate_lands(color_identity, 
                            landcount, 
                            whitecount, 
                            bluecount, 
                            blackcount, 
                            redcount, 
                            greencount)
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried following the same route, but to no avail. It ends up erroring out and not able to find the forms I'm requesting.

And here is the HTML index page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Commanderlands</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="lin_grad">
        <div class="col-12 title_card_bg">
            <h1 class="title_text hd-txt-con">Commanderlands.com</h1>
            <p class="subtitle">EDH Manabases Made Quickly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="float-child">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <form id="manabaseForm" action="/generate" method="post" class="manabase_form">
                            <div class="ci_directions">
                                <h1 class="text">Enter your deck's color identity below</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="colorIdInput" class="label-number">1)</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control cursor_test" id="colorIdInput" name="colorid"
                                       maxlength="5" placeholder="'WUBRG'">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="pip_directions">
                    <h1 class="text">2) Enter your deck's
                        color identity below</h1>
                </div>
                <form>
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/white_pip.png') }}" alt="Image" class="white inpt-dec-img">
                <input type="text" class="pip_count_entry inpt-dec" name="white_pip_count" maxlength="3"
                       onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/blue_pip.png') }}" alt="Image" class="blue_pip inpt-dec-img">
                <input type="text" class="pip_count_entry inpt-dec" name="blue_pip_count" maxlength="3"
                       onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/black_pip.png') }}" alt="Image" class="black_pip inpt-dec-img">
                <input type="text" class="pip_count_entry inpt-dec" name="black_pip_count" maxlength="3"
                       onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/red_pip.png') }}" alt="Image" class="red_pip inpt-dec-img">
                <input type="text" class="pip_count_entry inpt-dec" name="red_pip_count" maxlength="3"
                       onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/green_pip.png') }}" alt="Image" class="green_pip inpt-dec-img">
                <input type="text" class="pip_count_entry inpt-dec" name="green_pip_count" maxlength="3"
                       onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>
                <br>
                    
                <div>
                    <div class="cci_directions1 inpt-con">
                        <h1 class="text">3) Enter your desired land count</h1>
                        
                            <input type="text" class="pip_count_entry" name="max_land_count" maxlength="3"
                                  onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group2 gen-mb-btn">
                    <label for="colorIdInput" class="label-number">4)</label>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary gen-btn" id="generateButton">GENERATE MANABASE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="result">
                <textarea class="form-control land_list" name="land_list"
                          placeholder="Your generated manabase will appear here!" readonly>{{ result|safe }}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <div class="button-row">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary custom-btn" style="font-size: 12px;">Copy List</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary custom-btn" style="font-size: 12px;">Export to Moxfield</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-row">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary custom-btn" style="font-size: 12px;">Buy from TCGplayer</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary custom-btn" style="font-size: 12px;">Buy from Cardkingdom</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--for generate button-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
    var manabaseForm = document.getElementById("manabaseForm");

    generateButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        manabaseForm.submit();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am also getting the following error:

```
line 192, in __getitem__
  raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'max_land_count'
```

Comment: Most of your inputs aren't inside the `<form>`. You can add the `form="manabaseForm"` attribute to those inputs so they'll be included in the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is your form sending a GET request to the same endpoint from which it originates. The problem is you accepting only POST requests on /generate endpoint.

Also you have this error `KeyError: 'max_land_count'`. At first I'd use `request.form.get(key)` instead of `request.form[key]` because it will return `None` if key won't be found.

Try to `print(request.form)` to know which keys and values you're getting on the server side.